# Access structure members without using '.' or '->' operator

Tags: c, structure, dereference

How do I access keyValue and alternateKeyValue from the dell laptop definition without using the '.' or '->' operators to directly reference the qwerty struct or its members.

I tried looking for the solution but didn't find any. Could you please help me find a way to access it?

```
typedef enum
{
    MOUSE_NONE,
    MOUSE_UP,
    MOUSE_DOWN,
    MOUSE_LEFT,
    MOUSE_RIGHT,
} mouse_direction_E;

typedef struct
{
    bool leftButton;
    bool rightButton;
    bool middleButton;
    bool mouseOn;
    mouse_direction_E direction;
} mouse_S;

typedef struct
{
    char keyValue;
    char alternateKeyValue;
} keyboard_S;

typedef struct
{
    mouse_S simpleMouse;
    keyboard_S qwerty;
} laptop_S;

laptop_S dell =
{
    .simpleMouse =
    {
        .leftButton = false,
        .rightButton = false,
        .middleButton = false,
        .mouseOn = false,
        .direction = MOUSE_NONE,
    },
    .qwerty =
    {
        .keyValue = '5',
        .alternateKeyValue = '%'
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a homework question....

howzabout this:

```
int index = 0;
bool leftMouseButton = *( (bool *) &( ( (char*) &dell )[0]) );
/*                                              \ 1 / 
 *                                       \  2 /
 *                                                     \3/ 
 *                                 \___________ 4 _________/
 *                        \_ 5 _/
 *                     \_________________ 6 _________________/
 */
bool rightMouseButton = *( (bool *) &( ( (char*) &dell )[ sizeof(bool) - 1 ]) );
/* etc.  Enjoy the math! */
```

in words:

For any struct element located `x` bytes deep into `dell`

1. get the address of `dell`
2. Cast the address to a ptr to an array of bytes (chars) -- or if all of the struct content is the same size as `int`, then cast the address to `int*` (Remember to adjust subsequent math accordingly!)
3. Determine the offset of the desired element from the start of the struct `dell`.
4. Get the address for the desired element.
5. Cast that address to a ptr of the same type as the element we're presently working with.
6. Get the data at the address of the element we're presently working with.  In other words:  get the value of the element.

Tell me how I did on the assignment!

Comment: I got an error saying, error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer.

Comment: Right.  I know what I missed & will update.  Just need to do some extra `typedef`ing to keep the compiler happy.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation Der Schley.
One doubt that I have is wrt point 2. What if the struct has elements of various datatype? In that case, what do I need to cast the address to?

Comment: @PakkyaHadpad - Regardless of how many datatypes are in the struct, the math required to access an element must account for all prior elements in the struct:  arrays, ptrs, contents of contained structs, etc.

Comment: _gotta remember to stop hitting <cr> in these comment fields...._  Final comment:  the size of the index into the struct should be no bigger (`sizeof()`-wise) than the smallest element in the struct.  There would also be some rule to consider odd-sized elements, like `char* foo[3]`, but the compiler would likely leave a byte vacant and put the next element on the next word boundary,

Comment: Thank you for your answer and replies. It helped.. :) 
By the way, it is not a homework question, but one of the questions asked in an interview and I wasn't able to figure it out. Thanks to you, now I know how to do it... ;)

Comment: @PakkyaHadpad - That explains why you're working this issue on a weekend.  Good luck with the job hunt!

Comment: Thank you very much @Der Schley. Appreciate your help. :)